# What is the En-Route Information Display system (ERIDS) used for?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa

[ERIDS](http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/Publications/atpubs/FAC/0610.html) is an information display system used at Air Route Traffic Control Centers. It provides electronic access to things like NOTAMs and static documents that previously were only available in paper. It was Implemented around 2006.

I get that it provides a bunch of general information and NOTAMs and PIREPs and such, but who uses ERIDS to access that? I know controllers have their own display, and I was under the impression that NOTAMs and such could be accessed there. I would assume other personnel also have their own displays. Is ERIDS just like a back-up source of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just visited a facility and learned what this is.

ERIDS provides digital access to static documents like standard procedures and things of that nature. ERIDS provides easier access to these documents than would otherwise be possible. ERIDS also provides a way (not the only way) to access NOTAMs or PIREPS or send PIREPS. I know controllers have other ways to access this information; I am not sure about other personnel. Having multiple ways to access or send this information is helpful to controllers as there may be multiple controllers in a sector and they may need to both access these services.

Essentially, ERIDS is just an informational system that is easy to access in an air route traffic control facility.